# Como baixar TODOS os arquivos de uma pasta com requests?

Tags: python

Achei vários artigos na internet sobre como baixar um único arquivo, mas eu sempre preciso especificar o nome e diretório do arquivo.

O programa que eu gostaria de fazer precisa baixar **todos** os arquivos neste diretório (ex: `191.15.5.1/pasta`) e salvá-los no diretório padrão onde se encontra o app.

Fiz algo assim, mas não consegui concluir:

```
def get_arqchives(url):
    res = requests.get(url)
    if res.status_code == requests.codes.OK:
       for u in res.content:
           with (endereco, 'wb') as target:
               pass
    else:
       res.raise_for_status()
```

Answer (score 1):

Numa pasta HTTP apenas recebemos o HTML com a lista dos ficheiros. Temos que usar o BeautifulSoup para obter os links.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pathlib import Path

url = '191.15.5.1/pasta/'

def listFD(url):
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    return [url + '/' + node.get('href') for node in soup.find_all('a') if node.get('href')]

def downloadFile(file):
    r = requests.get(file)
    path = Path(file)
    with open(path.name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content) 

for file in listFD(url):
    downloadFile(file)
```

Comment: Obtive este erro:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dannyou/PycharmProjects/autoupdater/main.py", line 34, in <module>
    downloadFile(x)
  File "C:/Users/dannyou/PycharmProjects/autoupdater/main.py", line 29, in downloadFile
    with open(path.name, 'wb') as f:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '?C=N;O=D'`